# How to recover an hg shelve when its parent (or an ancestor) has been removed/stripped?

Tags: mercurial

I seem to have made a mistake when performing a series of rebase, strip, and shelve operations. The result is that I am unable to unshelve. When I run `hg unshelve` in the current state, it just throws an ugly error:

```
# hg unshelve
unshelving change 'repo-02'
abort: 00changelog.i@5bd4b71e0176: unknown parent!
```

I think what has happened is that after shelving a change (or maybe a series of shelves) I stripped / rebased away a commit which was a dependency of the shelf.

The shelf has changes to a number of "random" files - meaning their changes are unrelated (mainly temporary debug output, things like that). So even with the single stripped file gone, the remaining parts of the shelve should be OK to use - but how can I get past this error?

Comment: It sounds like you are using an obsolete workflow. You should be using the Evolve extension and Topics, which use non-destructive operations. And you should not use `hg strip`, which is destructive and has long been obsolete. And `hg shelve` is occasionally useful, but should not be part of your regular workflow either.

Comment: @FaheemMitha I do use Evolve also, I don't recall in this case why I did it differently.

Comment: If you use Evolve, there really is no reason to use `hg strip` for example. Unless Evolve has a non-destructive variant of it. Which seems unlikely, since it already has `hg prune`.

Answer (score 0):

One method of getting around this might be to undo the stripped changesets. But before I did that I found another method which worked, and I think this was ultimately simpler as I had a large # of strip backups to work through.

---

Looking in the `.hg\shelved\` folder I actually had data files from several shelve 'events'. They looked something like this:

```
repo-01.hg
repo-01.patch
repo-01.shelve
repo-02.hg
repo-02.patch
repo-02.shelve
repo.hg
repo.patch
repo.shelve
```

Reading these file contents I noticed that the `.patch` files were indeed standard diff-style patches.

Also by looking at the contents of all 3 shelves I could determine that it was only the "repo.patch" (the oldest one) that I actually needed.

(Initially I tried removing the 01 and 02 files and unshelving, but this produced a different error, so I reversed course.)

I then ran:

`hg patch --no-commit repo.patch`

from within that folder. This basically worked fine, and now my working folder contained modified files again, and they checked out as having the expected contents.

Interestingly because of the original mistake (stripping a commit) one of the files in that patch failed to apply - because the file no longer exists. But fortunately `hg patch` was resilient enough to just skip over this. Since the file was deleted intentionally, this was not a problem.

Following the above, I used:

`hg shelve --cleanup`

to get rid of the messy state. Shelve / unshelve now work normally again.